# check if repeating node is empty in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have xml like defined below . The node **EducationDetails** can repeat (unbounded).

```html
<PersonalDetailsResponse>
  <FirstName></FirstName>
  <LastName></LastName>
  <EducationDetails>
    <Degree></Degree>
    <Institution></Institution>
    <Year></Year>
  </EducationDetails>
  <EducationDetails>
    <Degree></Degree>
    <Institution></Institution>
    <Year></Year>
  </EducationDetails>
</PersonalDetailsResponse>
```

I want to create another xml from the above one using xslt.
My requirement is, if there is no data in any of the **EducationDetails** child nodes , then the resulting xml has to get data from another source.

My problem is , I am not able to check if all the **EducationDetails** child nodes are empty.

Since variable value cannot be changed in xslt , I tried using saxon with below code.

```
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" extension-element-prefixes="saxon"

                <xsl:variable name="emptyNode" saxon:assignable="yes" select="0" />

                    <xsl:when test="count(ss:education) > 0">
                        <xsl:for-each select="ss:education">
                                <xsl:if test="not(*[.=''])"> 
                            <saxon:assign name="emptyNode">
                                <xsl:value-of select="1" />
                            </saxon:assign>
                             </xsl:if> 
                        </xsl:for-each>

                        <xsl:if test="$emptyNode = 0"> 
                           <!-- Do logic if all educationdetails node is empty-->
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:when>
```

But it throwing exception "net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Unknown extension instruction "  . 
It looks like saxon 9 jar is required for it ,which I am not able to get from my repository.

Is there a simpler way to check if all the child nodes of  are empty. 
By empty I mean, child nodes might be present, but no value in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you use `<xsl:template match="PersonalDetailsResponse[EducationDetails[*[normalize-space()]]">...</xsl:template>` then you match only on `PersonalDetailsResponse` element having at least one `EducationDetails` element having at least one child element with non whitespace data. As you seem to use an XSLT 2.0 processor you can also use the perhaps clearer `<xsl:template match="PersonalDetailsResponse[some $ed in EducationDetails/* satisfies normalize-space($ed)]">...</xsl:template>`.

Or perhaps if you want a variable inside the template use

```
<xsl:template match="PersonalDetailsResponse">
  <xsl:variable name="empty-details" select="not(EducationDetails/*[normalize-space()])"/>
  <xsl:if test="$empty-details">...</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 2.0 the use of `some` or `every` `satisfies` might be easier to understand e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="PersonalDetailsResponse">
  <xsl:variable name="empty-details" select="every $dt in EducationDetails/* satisfies not(normalize-space($dt))"/>
  <xsl:if test="$empty-details">...</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But usually writing templates with appropriate match conditions saves you from using `xsl:if` or `xsl:choose` inside of a template.